# ¿Cómo puedo restar días en una cuenta regresiva en php?

Tags: php

Buen día, comunidad.

Estoy buscando como hacer una fecha regresiva de días, es decir, restar días de acuerdo a mi fecha que capture en un input date.
Por ejemplo:
Si capturo la fecha del día de hoy: 18/11/2020, en mi mensaje que pinte tiene que decir, faltan 30 días para que caduque el item. y conforme pasen los días tiene que restarle días a los 30.

Tengo  mi código y pinta los 30 días cuando capturo mi fecha en el input, sin embargo, aun no logro restar días a los 30 días.

```
   <?php
    
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
      $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
      $fecha_inicio = date_create($fecha);
      $fecha_final = date_create($row['fecha_item']);
       $cuenta_regresiva = date_diff($fecha_inicio,$fecha_final);
       $days = $cuenta_regresiva->d;
       if ($days==0){
          $days = 30;
       }
       echo'<td><span class="label label-default"> Faltan' . $days .  " 
         <br>Días para su vencimiento <br> del pedido ";
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Puedes capturar la fecha de inicio y a este sumarle 30 dias, luego cuentas cuantos dias le quedan disponibles para que caduque la fecha

Answer (score 0):

Para restar dias en php puedes hacer esto

```
<?php

$fecha_actual = date('d-m-Y');
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days")); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la fecha final almacenada en tu base de datos (teniendo en cuenta que ya se le han sumado los 30 días o la cantidad de días que sea) Por ejemplo:

**geek_root** hizo un pedido el día ***2020-11-05*** este pedido está supuesto a vencer el día ***2020-12-05*** tras haberle sumado los 30 días.

Teniendo esto en cuenta tu formula debería ser la siguiente (ya la tienes en tú código):

```
diasFaltantesParaVencimiento = fechaFinal - fechaActual
```

Traducido a PHP sería algo como esto (ignora las declaraciones de fecha inicial y fecha final):

```
$fechaActual = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$fechaFinal = date_create(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2020-11-05") + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30))) ;

$days = date_diff($fechaFinal, $fechaActual);

echo 'Faltan ' . $days->d." días";
```

Este código lo puedes copiar y pegar [aquí](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com) y probarlo de manera online.

**------ EDITADO ------**

No necesitas introducir la fecha en el ***input*** cada vez que que quieras ver cuanto falta, si tienes la fecha de caducidad/vencimiento. Como te sugiere el compañero ***ernesto*** suma 30 días a la fecha del input y luego solo tienes que seguir la formula de arriba. Usa el método [***format***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) para obtener los días de manera exacta:

```
 # fecha actual que tiene el servidor
 $fechaActual = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
 
 # vendría de la base de datos, pero aquí la ponemos manual :)
 $fechaFinal = date_create(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2020-11-19") + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30))) ;

# date_diff devuelve un objeto DateInterval
 $days = date_diff($fechaFinal, $fechaActual);

 $diasFaltantes = (int)$days->format('%a');

 echo "Falta ".$diasFaltantes. " días";
```

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro, y haberte ayudado con tu duda. Si tu problema persiste sería bueno que muestres un ejemplo de como sería la salida de tu programa o como funciona.

Comment: Hola amigo @Dionicio, cuando pongo mi campo de la base de datos en lugar de la fecha lo que hace es lo contrario tengo que poner hasta el 18-12-2020 para que vaya descontando los días, y si cambio la fecha en mi input hace lo mismo, quiero que en automático conforme pasen los días vaya restándolos sin necesidad de cambiar la fecha en mi input, es decir así:


<?php

  $fechaFinal = date_create(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['fecha_caducidad']) - (60 * 
  60 * 24 * 30))) ;

?>

Comment: Hola @Dionicio, muchas gracias si me sirvió. Saludos amigo